# Draggable from HTML droppable on SVG

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, svg, jquery-svg

I am using Jquery draggable on some pins... I need them to be dropped onto paths on an SVG map and return the id of that path. I cant seem to get it to work though.

Here is a snipped of my code. Ideally if i drag the sign on to this path I want to return 'map_1' from the id but the code I have doesn't seem to do it like how it normally works with non SVG.

```
<div class="signs s1 draggable"></div>

<svg version="1.1" id="map" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px" viewBox="0 0 540 360" xml:space="preserve">

    <!-- regions -->
    <g id="states">
        <g>
        <!-- AL -->
        <path  class="droppable al"id="map_1" fill="#EBECED" stroke="#FFFFFF" stroke-width="1" d="M336.6,199.5l-0.199,0.4l0.5,1.1l-3.301,32.399l0.9,17.5c1.6-0.399,2.4-0.699,2.4-1
            c-0.301-0.6-0.4-1.1-0.301-1.5c0.101-1.5,0.5-1.899,1.101-1.3c0.6,0.5,1,1.4,1.399,2.7c0.301,1.3,0.801,1.9,1.5,1.6
            c0.301-0.199,1-0.5,1.9-0.8c0.6-0.8,0.8-1.399,0.6-1.8c-0.3-0.5-0.3-1.1,0-1.7c0.301-0.7,0-1.2-0.8-1.5
            c-0.899-0.399-1.2-1.2-0.6-2.3h22.5c-0.4-1.6-0.601-2.7-0.3-3.3c0.199-0.7,0.199-2-0.301-3.8c-0.199-0.801-0.199-1.2-0.3-1.301
            c0-0.1,0.101-0.6,0.3-1.6c0.101-0.6,0.4-1.2,0.9-2c0.4-0.5,0.6-1.1,0.4-1.8c-0.101-0.7-0.5-1.5-0.9-2.4
            c-0.5-0.899-0.8-1.7-0.9-2.2l-3.8-25.399H336.6z" />
         </g>
    </g>
</svg>
```

JS

```
    $('.draggable').draggable();
    $('svg path.droppable').droppable({
        accept: '.draggable',
        drop: function( event, ui ) {
            console.log('event');
            console.log(event);
            console.log('ui');
            console.log(ui);
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

[**SVG Droppable**](http://bl.ocks.org/thudfactor/6611441)

Make use of this example...

```
var dropTargets = canvas.selectAll("rect").data(types).enter().append("g")

dropTargets.append("rect")
    .attr({
        width: 180,
        height: 100,
        x: 10.5,
        y: function(d,i) { return (i * 110) + .5},
        rx: 20,
        ry: 20,
        class: function(d,i) { return "color" + (i+1) }
    })

dropTargets.append("text")
    .text(function (d) { return d })
    .attr({
        x: 25.5,
        dy: 30,
        y: function(d,i) { return (i * 110) + .5}
    });
```

Append the svg dynamically to use like this...

Comment: confused as to how to make that work with the path... do I replace rect with my path bits

Comment: Its hectic to do with svg drop.. I ve never done this.. so oly i ve referred u a link... better try with canvas drag and drop

Answer (score 0):

Path element doesn't handles drop event, but it handles `mouseover` and `mouseout` events. So, you just need to use an external manager as well as it used here (http://bl.ocks.org/thudfactor/6611441 (You don't really need d3 here)) where you can save data of the dragged element on drag `start` event and handle drop on `stop` draggable event (you just need to clarify that `mouseover` of the droppable fired before drop).

LMK, if you need more details on it.